# Trigger Lambda function on receiving an email

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

I am trying to develop an solution where, I send an email to AWS and based on that, I want to trigger a Lambda function that will

How should this be achieved

Comment: "A Lambda function that will" You didn't complete your problem statement. Does the Lambda function need to read the email or something? Please edit your original question to include a complete problem statement.

Comment: Probably worth explaining what you mean by "send an email to AWS".

Answer (score 1):

From [Sample incoming email event - Amazon Simple Email Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/receiving-email-action-lambda-event.html):

> There are two ways to send incoming email events to a Lambda function. The first method is to **use a Lambda action in your receipt rule** to send the event record directly to the function. The second method is to **use an Amazon SNS action in your receipt rule** to send the event records to Amazon SNS, and then add the Lambda function as a subscribing endpoint to the Amazon SNS topic.

Comment: the problem is i do not how to send an email to aws. For example in one of the other tool we use like devinstance@company.com to send email to cloud instance lets say servicenow. In Aws what should be used so that i can process the email based on recipient rule

Comment: [Email receiving with Amazon SES - Amazon Simple Email Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/receiving-email.html)